# Java: Is it possible to throws IOException once and for all?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. And I find it really annoying to keep writing  `throws IOException` in the "main" and all the methods that open a file. For example:

```
class something{    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            myobj abc = new myobj();
            abc.read_file("this_file.txt");
            abc.insert("text");
    }
}

class myobj{
            ....

           public void read_file(String file_loc) throws IOException{
                blablabla
            }
    }
```

In this case, I have already written "throws IOException" twice. Is there a way to handle this once and for all ?

**Edit:**
Thanks for all the good answers. A lot of people suggested using try-catch statements. 
I read about try and catch statements and I got really confused. My question is where should I carry on writing my code i.e. `abc.insert("text")` into the try catch statements after `abc.read_file("this_file.txt")` ? Should I carry on in catch block or outside it ? This is what really puzzles me.

Comment: Catch the exception in `main` and handle it appropriately.

Comment: This is a language feature, not something you should fight against.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it can seems boring... but it is very very important. After some time passed over Java more complex works... you will appreciate the Java exception management... ;)

Comment: It is, well without a NullPointerException there's no java. You'll see that a lot this one learning this language. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to Java.

Hi, I hope you enjoy your learning. Learning a new programming language effectively implies learning the idiomatic ways in which to code in that language (even the ones that we subjectively find annoying.)

This is not unique to Java. Whether you do C# or Python or C++ or Haskell, you will be bound to find something that is annoying. Then the question is, what value do you get in the effort to avoid that annoyance.

If you become more productive by avoiding the annoyance, then more power to you. Otherwise, I would follow Maya Angelou's advice: `"If you don't like something, change it. If you can't change it, change your attitude."`

> And I find it really annoying to keep writing 
>   throws IOException in the "main" and all the methods that open a file.

In real life development, you will be handling far more non-main exceptions that main ones (probably only one main.)

So what is the threshold, the ration of main/(all other functions) by which the annoyance is justifiable and constructive? One main and one function? One main and a dozen? One main and a hundred?

Of all the plumbing and elbow grease that needs to be done with Java, declaring exceptions on the main function is an exercise in emotion of very little use.

So take it with a grain of salt, but in my professional opinion (18 years, Java, C++, Python and a lot of other crap) is this: declare your exceptions, even on main.

Why? Because it is possible that other programs might invoke your main. That is, your Java program might be invoked from the console, or it might be **embedded** (invokable?) from another program.

I've done this a lot for testing or for developing systems that are *embeddable*. So, in this case,
you want to declare those exceptions. However, since such a program is intended for standalone and embedded use, this is the general pattern I follow (java-like pseudocode, far more simplified than real-life code):

```
class UtilityDelegate {
    UtilitytDelegate(){ .... }

    void performWork(File f) throws IOException {
        // do something with file
    }
}

public class SomeUtility {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = null;
        try{
            // do something that could throw an exception
            f = new File(args[0]);
            performWork(f);
        } finally {
            // do necessary clean-up, if any, such as closing file handles,
            // sockets, flushing database changes, pray to Lord Xenu, whatever

            if( f != null ){
                try{
                    f.close();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); // or use a logging mechanism or whatever
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your program can be called from the command line:

```
java SomeUtility myfile
```

Or from another java class:

```
public class SomeUtilityClient{
    public static void main(final String[] args){
        // for brevity, I'm omitting the case when the utility might
        // call System.exit() itself.
        try{
            SomeUtility.main("a-pre-defined-filename");
        } catch(IOException e){
            someLog("call to utility failed, see exception", e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

An argument could be made that such a java client should call the embedded program via another method name, not main. That is fair, and in many cases, it is the better approach.

But just consider this one reason or approach of why to declare your exceptions everywhere, even on your main.

Answer (score 3):

Who is main throwing to?  No one.

Java has checked and unchecked exceptions.  Checked exceptions leave you no choice: you either have to catch them or add them to your method signature in a throws clause.

Unchecked exceptions don't require handling.

You always have the option of catching a checked exception and rethrowing it as a custom unchecked exception.

I'd write it this way:

```
class something{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        try {
            myobj abc = new myobj();
            abc.read_file("this_file.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class myobj{
            ....

           public void read_file(String file_loc) throws IOException{
                blablabla
            }
    }
```

Comment: But this is just what the default exception handler will do anyway so what is the advantage of this?  Personally, I'm getting very suspect if I see `catch`-`printStackTrace` constructs as they are a common symptom of “getting rid” of exceptions, rather than dealing with them properly.  Unfortunately, a popular IDE encourages this idiom by its default code generation.

Comment: I typically do a different approach and I make main declare it's checked exceptions. Then, I do any necessary clean-ups in a try/finally, letting the exception bubble up. The reason for this is that sometimes (be it for testing or integration) other code might invoke another class's main with pseudo-CLI arguments  computed programmatically or declaratively or what not. Unless I have a really good reason, I never expect my main functions to be called **exclusively** from the command line.

Comment: What does "dealing with them properly" look like, especially in this contrived, simplistic example?  By all means know that handling should be more than printing the stack trace, but in this case it's a main method.  It's the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

There's no catch-all "all methods in this class throw this exception," you'll have to declare the exception on each method (e.g., `read_file`, etc.) or handle it within the method. This is the point of checked exceptions: To ensure that at each stage, it's clear where they may come from and where they're handled.

---

Note: `main` shouldn't throw, you should catch the exception and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The main method doesn't need to throw anything.

```
class something{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        try {
            myobj abc = new myobj();
            abc.read_file("this_file.txt");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I know you may find this language feature annoying but trust me, it is far less frustrating than managing code which does not propagate exceptions. You spend hours and hours wondering why your code is not doing something and then you stumble across this:

```
try {
    doSomethingImportant();
}
catch(Exception e) {
   // Nah can't be bothered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, no.

There are two ways to deal with exceptions:

1. You either handle that exception in your current method (main in your case) by surrounding the API that throws the exception with try-catch and writing code in the catch block to handle it OR
2. Add "throws IOException" on the method signature in which case you force the callers of your method to deal with it.